# Javascript Promise with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

```
const sleep = (time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

const doSomething = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    await sleep(1000)
    console.log(i)
  }
}

doSomething()
```

Why is this promise working as expected? I'm learning about Promise and stuck on this. The function passed into the Promise constructor does not have reject() and yet it is working.

The snippet is from this article: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-slow-down-for-loop-9d1caaeeeeed
I'm also struggling to understand the explanation in the article about the differences between the setTimeout approach (that does not work) vs. setTimeout in promise approach (that works).

Thanks for any pointer on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments are optional in JavaScript so the `reject` argument is just ignored.

As for why the first example doesn't work is that `setTimeout` registers an event for the event loop to call in the future. Things in JavaScript do not block. Internally `await` rewrites the code so that it does not block, but the code still reads as synchronous, but it is not.

There are plenty of great examples out there explaining the JavaScript event loop, and I'd highly suggest reading up on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Promise` is not resolved until the `resolve` (`"res"`) function is called. The function that gets passed to `setTimeout` does not run until the timeout finishes.

Here is an alternative example, where the `resolve` function returns the `count` that gets passed-in.

```js
const main = async () => {
  const done = await doSomething(10, 1000, i => console.log(i));
  console.log('Done!');
};

const doSomething = async (times, duration, callback) => {
  for (let counter = 0; counter < times; counter++) {
    const count = await sleep(counter, duration);
    callback(count);
  }
  return true;
};

const sleep = (count, duration) => {
  return new Promise((res) => setTimeout((n) => res(n), duration, count));
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

Here is a less-coupled version, with some default parameters.

```js
const DEBUG = true;

const main = async () => {
  const worker = (n, m) => console.log(`Step ${n + 1}/${m}`);
  await doSomething(worker);
};

const doSomething = async (callback, duration = 1000, times = 10) => {
  if (DEBUG) console.log('Start!');
  for (let counter = 0; counter < times; counter++) {
    await sleep(duration, counter, times);
    callback(counter, times);
  }
  if (DEBUG) console.log('Done!');
  return true;
};

const sleep = (duration, count = 1, times = 1) => {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, duration));
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```